# MS Access form; only lock the controls when value is 0 and not when the value is empty

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, locked

I need to lock all controls on the main form and a subform when the total of the sub form is 0. The unbound control on the main form holding the value is named `sumBalance` with the control source picking up the sum of the sub form `=Nz([frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf]![JournalTotal],"")`

I have made two alternative VBA codes in the current event on the main form:

```
If IsNull(Me!sumBalance) Then
        Me!fin_trans_id.Locked = False
        Me!fin_trans_tstamp.Locked = False
        Me!fin_trans_description.Locked = False
        Me!frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf.Locked = False
    ElseIf Me!sumBalance < 0 Then
        Me!fin_trans_id.Locked = False
        Me!fin_trans_tstamp.Locked = False
        Me!fin_trans_description.Locked = False
        Me!frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf.Locked = False
    ElseIf Me!sumBalance > 0 Then
        Me!fin_trans_id.Locked = False
        Me!fin_trans_tstamp.Locked = False
        Me!fin_trans_description.Locked = False
        Me!frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf.Locked = False
    ElseIf Me!sumBalance = 0 Then
        Me!fin_trans_id.Locked = True
        Me!fin_trans_tstamp.Locked = True
        Me!fin_trans_description.Locked = True
        Me!frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf.Locked = True
End If
```

```
If Me!sumBalance = 0 Then
        Me!fin_trans_id.Locked = True
        Me!fin_trans_tstamp.Locked = True
        Me!fin_trans_description.Locked = True
        Me!frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf.Locked = True
    Else
        Me!fin_trans_id.Locked = False
        Me!fin_trans_tstamp.Locked = False
        Me!fin_trans_description.Locked = False
        Me!frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf.Locked = False
End If
```

I would have expected both of the VBA codes would result in the main forms controls and the sub form would be unlocked in every other condition than when the control `sumBalance` = 0.

But when the `sumBalance` field is empty due to no records in the sub form, the form is also locked preventing from making new records.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could eliminate repetition of `Me` by using `With Me ... End With` wrapper. Use dot instead bang when referencing controls in VBA. Could use textbox and combobox Conditional Formatting to enable/disable. ID controls should probably always be locked or don't even show ID. sumBalance can never be Null because of Nz() function setting control to empty string - an empty string is < 0. In my test, textbox is empty string when subform does not have records. Have you step debugged?

Comment: Simplify code. Set a Boolean variable and reference that in setting Locked property. `booLock = .sumBalance = 0` then 4 lines to lock/unlock like `.frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf.Locked = booLock`

Comment: I did some testing. When I set a breakpoint and step through code it works properly, but without breakpoint it goes haywire. I don't have solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot check records not being there, so first count the records:

```vb
Dim Locked As Boolean

If Me!NameOfYourSubformCONTROL.Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount > 0 then
    Locked = (Nz(Me!sumBalance.Value, 0) = 0)
End If

Me!fin_trans_id.Locked = Locked
Me!fin_trans_tstamp.Locked = Locked
Me!fin_trans_description.Locked = Locked
Me!frm_0_accs_fin_trans_journ_subf.Locked = Locked
```

Comment: Great idea. Nz() is probably not necessary since if there are records, sumBalance should always have a value. But it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Worked like a charm, also without Nz(). Thanks, a lot.